# CSS: transform:scale - img tag with two classes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize pictures on an responsive website using **transform:scale** in CSS. I want to keep the aspect ratio. So I created two classes for the . The two classes are according to weather the picture is landscape or portrait.

My HTML:

`<img class="landscape" src="" width=100%; height=100%> 
 <img class="portrait" src="" width=100%; height=100%>`

My CSS:

```
img.ladscape { transform:scale(0.745,0.671);}
img.portrait { transform:scale(0.671,0.745);}
```

The landscape picture gets right scaled.
The portrait format one does not get scaled right.

Where is my mistake?

I also want an third class for square-format pictures.

Thanks for your help.

-Cevin

Comment: I just updated ur post. plz share ur full code or create a demo and remove ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set width and height that point to the area of the display dimension .
 If you remove them you can see the difference

```
img.quer {
    transform:scaleX(0.745) scaleY(0.671);
}

img.hoch {
    transform:scaleX(0.671) scaleY(0.745);
}
```

---

```
<img class="quer" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" >   
<img class="hoch" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSobAPMeqgsRtHrX8vclVHPggkhqcSt0q1ixhyokNq3Wa16TGF6Mp34Cjo" >
```

---

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dqypm8yh/
```

Because the width of the screen is bigger than height (on monitor) the landscape will scale better

Comment: Awsome, thank you. Now scrolling is strange. Because of the big image I can scroll in x and y dimension. How to I fix this?

Comment: @CevinFreitag Also the dimension of the photos can affect the quality ,if you scale them with same values then the images should have the same resolution to get the same result

Comment: @CevinFreitag what are you doing with that? We can't help 100% without knowing what you are thinking.

Comment: @CevinFreitag The image that I used is just an example,you can set its width (only width) to 20% for example and then scale it again